# iReport: Load Subreport From Database

Tags: jasper-reports, blob, subreport

I have report that uses a subreport, but since the subreport is stored in a database table as `BLOB`, I cannot give its path (url) in the `*.jrxml` file. Is there a way to add a `*.jasper` file loaded from the database (`BLOB` or `InputStream`) as a subreport.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out.

1. Add a list component
2. In the list's dataset fetch the field you keep your subreport as a BLOB, lets call it
   `REPORT_DATA`.
3. Set `REPORT_DATA` field's type to `InputStream`.
4. Add the subreport inside the list.
5. Set "Subreport Expression" to `$F{REPORT_DATA}` and its "Expression
   Class" to `InputStream`.
6. Set Connection type, expression, and parameters accordingly.

Don't forget to resize the list component at least to the subreport's size, otherwise you get an error like :

```
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.design.JRValidationException: Band height validation for subreport ...
```