# How add subreports dinamyc in jasperreport

Tags: java, jasper-reports, subreport

It's possible to create one report with two subreport and put all files in my db? so, how can I pass to fill the subreport in my main report? I need to sabe the subreports in a Temp file, and pass the directory? or have some way to add the subreport in the jasperPrint and he locate the sub automatic?

this is my code:

```
try (Connection conexao = dataSource.getConnection()){
        FinanceiroTransacao transacao = financeiroTransacaoService.findGatewayIdTransacaoByBoletoAndCartorio(boletoId, cns);
        JasperReport jasperReport;
        jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(JRXmlLoader.load(new ByteArrayInputStream(relatorioBase.getConteudo())));
        Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>();
        params.put("pedidoId", pedidoId);
        params.put("boletoId", boletoId);
        params.put("cartorio",cns);
        params.put("totalTransacao", transacao.getValorCredito());
        params.put("idTransferencia", transacao.getGatewayPagamentoTransacaoId());
        params.forEach((s, o) -> log.debug("paramentro {} , valor {}", s, o));

        subReports.forEach(subReport -> {
           //HERE I NEED TO add the sub reports 
        });
        JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, params, conexao);

        JRPdfExporter pdfExporter = new JRPdfExporter();
        pdfExporter.setExporterInput(new SimpleExporterInput(jasperPrint));
        ByteArrayOutputStream pdfReportStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        pdfExporter.setExporterOutput(new SimpleOutputStreamExporterOutput(pdfReportStream));
        pdfExporter.exportReport();
        String retorno = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(pdfReportStream.toByteArray());
        pdfReportStream.close();
        return retorno;
    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw new RuntimeException("erro: "+ e.getMessage());
    }
```

Comment: Possible similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23082712/ireport-load-subreport-from-database

Answer (score -1):

The first thing you have to do it's create a parameter: "SUBREPORT_DIR" in your jaspert report that will be the location of you subreport, so you can do this in the XML of you report.

```
</subreport>
   <connectionExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_CONNECTION}]]></connectionExpression>
   <subreportExpression><![CDATA[$P{SUBREPORT_DIR} + "NameSubrport.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
</subreport>
```

This is for every subreport so you let the name of the report static.
So in your java you have to pass the url of the location, you can do that with this:

```
Resource r = ApplicationContextProvider.getApplicationContext().getResource("/resources/reports");
String reportPath = r.getFile().getAbsolutePath();
params.put("SUBREPORT_DIR", reportPath + File.separator);
```

(Remember the `.getResource`, its to get the correct path of the folder where are the reports in your project in runtime)

In this way works for me. I hope this help!

Comment: I dont have any file in my HD, all my reports are in my DB (Postgresql) so how I pass the subreport without the name?